# Android Studio can't resolve new XML layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm making customized contacts app, which one of it's features are to send SMS.
All was going good until I wanted to create my sixth XML layout which 'setContentView' couldn't resolve, even if I'm deleting the layout and auto-creating it by using `Alt+Enter`.

I've looked up for solutions in here.
It's not related to R.java.
I made all to make sure the layout name is not misspelled.

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_sendsms);`

The layout is 100% there but still I'm getting from Android Studio the error:
`Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_sendsms'`
[the eror and the show it's in the right place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9tmq.jpg)

Do I need to import something which I'm not doing right? (all others .java file imports are pretty much the same)
The imports:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Comment: remove the setContentView line of code and recompile the app. See if you can find any errors somewhere

Comment: You need to add `import YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.R`

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuild the project?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently restarting Android Studio did the trick.
Thanks all for answering.